# hidden field in angular is null on form submit

Tags: angularjs, hiddenfield

I'm loading a page with a question and options where the question id is a hidden filed to pass to a method to save the answer.

but the field is returned as null though the output value from a http service is stored on page init.

please share your thoughts.

thanks.

Comment: you can use like this. `<input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="hiddenField">`

Comment: Thanks you @Hadi. I tried but it didn't work. Now i have found an alternate way to set the variable up on user action instead of the hidden field.